# If an API only provides POST requests functions, is it RESTful?

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

I'm not sure I understand correctly the notion of RESTful API. If I understand correctly, such an API should provide functions you can trigger with GET, POST, PUT & DELETE requests. My question is: if an API only provides POST requests functions, is it still RESTful?

Comment: Yes - it is still RESTul

Comment: I wonder, why there is vote to close the topic? It is not opinion based question and it is directly related to programming!

Comment: It is an *architecture* question, not a *programming* question @SaidbakR

Comment: @JayBlanchard However, it is still meant by programming. The `restful` tag is suffixed with `architecture` too. i.e there is a tag that allows talking about it.

Comment: I think others may be reading this as *"if an API only provides this method is it still this architecture?"* @SaidbakR Just because the tag exists doesn't mean you can ask non-programming questions about it. The OP did not provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), for example.

Comment: I'd say that this question seems _not concrete_ enough (?), generating possible discussion (as already in the comments of the answers). Like those old locked questions with this text: _"This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here."_, we do have locked questions that are good, but they still are not evidence to ask more questions like them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

REST is a misused term for some time and the community especially at Stackoverflow doesn't even care about its actual intention, the *decoupling of clients from server APIs in a distributed system*.

Client and server achieve the decoupling by following certain recommendations like avoiding stateful connections where client state is stored at and managed by the server, using unique identifiers for resources (URIs) and further nice-to-have features like cacheability to reduce the workload both server and clients have to perform. While [Fieldings dissertation](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) lists 6 constraints, [he later on explained some further rules applications following the REST architectural style have to follow](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) and the benefits the system gains by following these. Among these are:

- The API should not depend on any single communication protocol and adhere to and not violate the underlying protocol used. Altough REST is used via HTTP most of the time, it is not restricted to this protocol.
- Strong focus on resources and their presentation via media-types.
- Clients should not have initial knowledge or assumptions on the available resources or their returned state (["typed" resource](http://soabits.blogspot.co.at/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html)) in an API but learn them on the fly via issued requests and analyzed responses. This gives the server the opportunity to move arround or rename resources easily without breaking a client implementation.

So, basically, if you limit yourself only to HTTP you somehow already violate the general idea REST tries to impose.

As @tereško mentioned the Richardson maturity model I want to clarify that this model is rather nonsense in the scope of REST. Even if level 3 is reached it does not mean that this architecture follows REST. And any application that hasn't reached level 3 isn't following this architectural style anyways. Note that an application that only partially follows REST isn't actually following it. It's like either properly or not at all.

In regards to `RESTful` (the dissertation doesn't contain this term) usually one regards a JSON based API exposed via HTTP as such.

To your actual question:

Based on this quote

> ... such an API should provide functions you can trigger with GET, POST, PUT & DELETE requests

in terms of REST architectural style I'd say NO as you basically use such an API for RPC calls (a relaxed probably JSON based SOAP if you will), limit yourself to HTTP only and do not use the semantics of the underlying HTTP protocol fully; if you follow the JSON based HTTP API crowd the answer is probably *it depends on who you ask*  as there is no precise definition of the term "RESTful" IMO. I'd say no here as well if you trigger functions rather than resources on the server.

Answer (score 7):

You should probably watch [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pspy1H6A3FM) and read [this article](https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html).

REST a such has nothing to do with how much of available HTTP methods you use. So, the quick answer is: **yes, it could** be considered "restful" (whatever that actually means).

Buuut ... **it most likely - isn't**. And it has nothing to do with the abuse of `POST` calls.

The main indicator for this magical "RESTfulness" has nothing really to do with how you make the HTTP request (methods and pretty URLs are <strike>pointless</strike> *worthless as a determining factor*).

What matters is the returned data and whether, by looking at this data, you can learn about other resources and actions, that are related the resource in any given endpoint. It's basically about the discover-ability.

Comment: Not at all. You clearly dont know the subject. Read this if you mind http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html
As someone already said, Restful is an architecture, and it has some guidelines. I wouldn't expect a Restful API to have a GET that deletes something when I call it. It has a lot of aspects, it's not only about the data. It's also not about URLs being "pretty", there should be "atomicity" when you use URLs, etc.

Comment: @Martin I think you mis-read what I wrote. Or you have no understanding of what REST is.

Comment: No, I read correctly. You wrote (methods and pretty URLs are pointless) which is totally false.

Comment: Sorry .. I meant "worthless as a determining factor". Updated.

Comment: It does matter, and is determining. In fact the lecture you provided shows how to refer to resources using URLs, and talks about safe GETs.
Quoted from the lecture link you provided:
"So now rather than making all our requests to a singular service endpoint, we now start talking to individual resources." which has to do with URL naming.
"Level 2 moves away from this, using the HTTP verbs as closely as possible to how they are used in HTTP itself."  which talks about the importance of HTTP verbs.
I think you are misleading the person who asked.

Comment: I read a book: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028468.do, so no need for those links. Bye!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Restful has some guidelines you should follow. As long as you use HTTP verbs correctly and good practices with regards to URLs naming having only POSTs would be OK. If, on the other hand, a POST request in your application can also delete a record, then I would not call it Restful.

Comment: My answer stands true. If you down-vote you should explain why.